# responsive email not working gmail .com/ inbox.google.com on desktop browser

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, gmail, google-inbox

I have a responsive email template. it is rendering well on mobile apps but on browser its responsive behaviour not working. even inbox.google.com is responsive but the responsive emails are not working in it.

for reference i used many email templates available on github. But the result is same.

https://github.com/InterNations/antwort

Can anyone help me fixing it for gmail and inbox

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show expected behaviour and actual behaviour along with error messages. A Short, Self Contained, Correct Example would be useful

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, more info is needed to give exact answer - but if the template uses media queries or different mobile specific CSS it is likely not getting rendered by gmail as gmail cuts out all style tags in head and body.  [Css support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) in html email.